# How to trigger a process based on an Azure ML model predictions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-eventgrid

It is possible to trigger, let's say, a process to send emails or SMS based on an Azure ML prediction?

I have a customer segmentation model, and my goal is to contact a customer based on their segment. For example:

- All customers group A -> phone call.
- All customers group B -> SMS.

And so on...

How can I achieve this? How would be the recommended approach?
I was reading this [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-event-grid) but these event driven actions are not what I need.

Another thing that I was considering is what about saving the model response on a storage account and create a event action with Logic Apps or Azure Functions when adding data in this storage. This could work? Perhaps, it is important to mention that the model predictions are considered to be done once a month by a scheduled python script.

Can someone give me an advice to what path can I follow?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds using logic apps is when the responses are getting added storage account, to automate this you can use `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` trigger with `Azure Communication Services SMS` and `Send an email (V2)` actions to send the SMS and Emails to the customers.

Consider the below is your Response which is getting stored to your storage account

[image]

Here is my logic app flow

[image]